# Reading a File into a Byte Array (PHP)

Tags: php, streaming

I have one file. but now need to read this file into a bytes array. In java or c++ it's very easy to do that. but not found how i can read in PHP.

Answer (score 10):

You can read the file into a string like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("/tmp/some_file.txt");
```

You can get at the individual bytes similar to how you would in C:

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
    $char = $data[$i];
    echo "Byte $i: $char\n";
}
```

References:

- http://php.net/file_get_contents
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Comment: I think there is a typo. It must be:
`$char = $data[$i];`

Answer (score 4):

See the [PHP Manual on String access and modification by character](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)

> Characters within string s may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in `$str[42]`. Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose. The functions `substr()`  and `substr_replace()`  can be used when you want to extract or replace more than 1 character.

Or, if you are after seeking and reading bytes from the file, you can use an [SplFileObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgetc.php)

```
$file = new SplFileObject('file.txt');
while (false !== ($char = $file->fgetc())) {
    echo "$char\n";
}
```

That's not a byte array though, but iterating over a file handle. SplFileInfo implements the [SeekableIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.seekableiterator.php) Interface.

And on a sidenote, there is also

- [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) — Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached. Upon failure, file() returns FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file with either [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/function.fread.php) or [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php), then split it with [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/function.str-split.php):

```
$MyArray = str_split($file);
```

Answer (score 2):

too much php>

`$data = file_get_contents("/tmp/some_file.txt");`

best way to make for (not recomended in for use count, sizeof, strlen or other functions):
`$counter = strlen($data);
for($i = 0; $i < $counter; ++$i) {
    $char = data[$i];
    echo "Byte $i: $char\n";
}`

Comment: pointless micro-optimization. and your answer should have been a comment below the answer as well.

Comment: Of all micro optimizations, this one is the least pointless if at all.

Comment: @Raveren Even for an array containing the numbers 1 to 1M, using `for` with `count` requires a mere ~0.8s more. For 1-10k, this is already 0.002s only. And for less than that it's hardly measurable.

Comment: I left out this optimization for the sake of simplicity.