# array read by one element

Tags: php, arrays

I have bytes file. Now need to read it by one bytes. How i can make that?

Its possible read array and remove readed element?

Comment: This seems to be two different and entirely unrelated questions

Comment: How is that different to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620175/reading-a-file-into-a-byte-array-php?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're reading from the front of the array, you want `array_shift`.  You can read more at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php .

Do note that `array_shift` is linear in the size of the array, not constant time.  If you really must follow this model, you might want to reverse the array first and use `array_pop` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file for reading with [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and use [`fread()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) with a length of 1

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [**`fgetc`**](http://fr.php.net/fgetc) function, to read one character/byte from a file -- and calling it in a loop.

Quoting the given example :

```
$fp = fopen('somefile.txt', 'r');
if (!$fp) {
    echo 'Could not open file somefile.txt';
}
while (false !== ($char = fgetc($fp))) {
    echo "$char\n";
}
```

This will work as PHP considers that one character == one byte *(which is not always true... but that's another problem ^^ )*

Answer (score 0):

[`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) will remove the first element of an array.

Reading from a file is usually done with strings though, in which case you should store the index of the character being worked on, and advance it when you've handled the current character.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and read byte by byte with [unpack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php).

Answer (score 0):

To read only one byte of a file with php:

```
$fh = fopen('mytest.txt', "r");
$contents = fread($fh, 1);
```