# FileByteArray in PHP

Tags: php, file, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading a File into a Byte Array (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620175/reading-a-file-into-a-byte-array-php)

I need this below (C#) method in php, any help?

```
   private byte[] FileByteArray(string filePath) {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
        Stream st = sr.BaseStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(st);
        byte[] arrBytes = br.ReadBytes((st.Length + 1));
        br.Close();
        st.Close();
        return arrBytes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$content = file_get_contents($filePath);
// now we can access $content as an byte array
for ($i = 0, $c = strlen($content); $i < $c; $i++)
  echo($content[$i]);
```