# How to compare the final byte of file in PHP

Tags: php, binaryfiles

How would you do, in PHP, to open a binary file (PDF) and see if in the last byte is a x0D?

I have some PDFs which I need to be sure that have a ending x0A instead of x0D before sending it to a program.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620175/reading-a-file-into-a-byte-array-php

Comment: @GregaMenih Thanks. I will base on it, of course, reading a PDF into a string, is not what I want, for a matter of memory. I will try with fseek or something like that.

Comment: If you use file_get_contents() you'll have to read the entire file into memory. See [fseek()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) with the SEEK_END parameter.

Answer (score 1):

open your file with `$pdf = file_get_contents('your_file.pdf');`, then check your string with regex `preg_match("/x0D$/", $pdf);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
fseek($fp, -1, SEEK_END);
$lastByte = $data = fgets($fp);
```