# Get Zipfile as Bytes in php?

Tags: php

Using php, how can I read a zip file and get its bytes, for example something like

```
$contents = file_get_contents('myzipfile.zip');
echo $contents;
// outputs: 504b 0304 1400 0000 0800 1bae 2f46 20e0
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a File into a Byte Array (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620175/reading-a-file-into-a-byte-array-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents` gets the raw bytes, your `echo` outputs those raw bytes. If you expect to output a *hexadecimal notation* of the raw byte contents instead, use [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/bin2hex):

```
echo bin2hex($contents);
```

If you want that arbitrarily grouped with a space every two bytes, you can do something along these lines:

```
echo join(' ', str_split(bin2hex($contents), 4));
```

(Note that this is all rather inefficient, modifying the entire, possibly many megabyte large file in memory. I'm expecting this is just for debugging purposes, so won't go out of my way to write super efficient code.)

Comment: I used this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents()` will return the exact contents of the file, so the format depends on the file type.

If you are looking for the byte size of the file you can get any available file information with the core SPL library's fileInfo class:

```
$info = new SplFileInfo('myzipfile.zip');
$bytes = $info->getSize();
```